# How to keep area selected on click instead of over

Tags: css, xhtml

I tried active but when I unclicked it wouldn't stay selected.

Here is where I am trying to do it. You will see that On the hover it gets selected.

http://www.prototypesyndicate.com/_forms/marketing_packages.html#premium

Comment: In this case, javascript is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery to the rescue.  There is more than one way to skin this cat.

```
$('.area').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('selectedArea');
    $(this).removeClass('notSelectedArea');
}, function() {
    $(this).addClass('notSelectedArea');
    $(this).removeClass('selectedArea');
});
```

You can't activate it.  you need to have a css class that dictates the look of the area when it is "selected" and a class that dictates how it looks when not selected.  Then just swap them out with jquery.